# selection more than one value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need multiple select from option value for that I used [this](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) link 
But in this link only one option can be selected and I want more than one to select at a time. So how to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to get the :selected items from a multiple-selection select? Or do you want do get the selected options in all selects in a page?

Comment: actually i want that when I will click on one option it will be selected as it happening on the link now again I will select another one it will again add to the red one just like before

Answer (score 1):

Your `<select>` element must have multi-select enabled.

```
<select multiple>
```

**[Example: normal select vs multiple select.](http://jsfiddle.net/LAvYQ/)**